# How to add pull down menu into current window in Gnome

Tags: gnome-shell, globalmenu

I have ubuntu 18.04 and Gnome 3.28.3 but its very very annoying that I can't have the menus in the current window like so:

[image]

Is this possible without switching to mate or cinnamon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Gnome Shell and its default applications (Evince, Files, ...) by design. Practically any other desktop environment still supports the use of a classical pull down menu's and will offer utilities where these menus are embedded in the current window. So indeed, you will need to move to another desktop environment if this is important to you.

If you want to stay close to Gnome, you may want to try Cinnamon or Mate. Both provide versions of the file manager. document viewer, etc. that are essentially based on (sometimes former versions of) the corresponding gnome tools, but maintain the classical pull down menu.

Comment: That is a shame, I do love Gnome and its nicely skinned with ubuntu. But yes, not having the menus in the window means everything to me, so that is a shame.

Comment: This is really a design decision of Gnome. It is then up to applications to follow that or not follow that. Core applications of the Gnome Desktop obviously follow that design decision. So really, unfortunately, it is a matter of choosing a different DE.

Comment: Tears mate!!! Massive tears lol